# How does caller know which member functions of same name shall be called

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I see the below code today.

I know the difference between returning a reference and returning a const reference.

But I don't know when **T& operator*()** will be called, and when const **T& operator*()const** will be called.

They have the same name.

```
template<typename T>
class CSmartPtr
{
public:
    CSmartPtr(T *ptr = nullptr) :mptr(ptr) {}
    ~CSmartPtr() { delete mptr; }

    T& operator*() { return *mptr; }
    const T& operator*()const { return *mptr; }

private:
    T *mptr;
};
int main()
{
    CSmartPtr<int> ptr(new int);
    *ptr = 20;
    cout << *ptr << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `const` version is called if the `this` pointer is `const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I don't know when T& operator()* will be called, and when const T& operator()const* will be called.
>
> They have the same name.

In this case, if the member function is called on a `const` object, the `const` method will be invoked, and the non-const method will be invoked for a non-const object.

> How does caller know which member functions of same name shall be called?

They don't know that, and they *shouldn't* know that either. The whole point of overload sets is that the caller doesn't know which exact overload is called. That is intended to be an implementation detail. The caller should use the same syntax when they call a function from an overload set.

It's up to the author of the overload set that the right thing is done depending on the arguments that the function is called with.

If you do want the caller to know which function is called, then *don't* use an overload set at all, just provide functions with different names.

Comment: Hmm, why isn't this answer considered useful?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Seems like I'm not getting an explanation from either of the DVers. Oh well :(